# Python- Can not install HTSEq

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics, pysam

I can not install HTSeq in python 3.6.1.

When I try to install, it gives me this error:

```
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'[0m 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the HTSeq installation docs [here](http://www-huber.embl.de/HTSeq/doc/install.html#install): `"To use HTSeq, you need at least version 2.5 of Python (Python 3 does not work yet)"`.

You need to install Python2 on your machine and try installing with that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually HTSeq works in Python3 quite nicely, and I can confirm it running in python 3.5.1 on several systems.
See also here: https://github.com/simon-anders/htseq

However, since the author claims it has been tested up to 3.6, I guess it should also work in python 3.6.